# @Transactional method calling another method without @Transactional annotation works for save but does not work for update

Tags: java, spring, transactions

I know this question has been [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6222600/transactional-method-calling-another-method-without-transactional-anotation) before,  but I can't still understand what is wrong with the following code:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public void doStuff(User user, Address address) {
    userService.save(user);
    addressService.update(address);
}
```

Below the following classes using Spring Data

```
@Service
public class UserService {
    public User save(User user) {
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }
}
```

-

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>, UserRepositoryCustom  {

}
```

-

```
@Service
public class AddressService {
    public Address update(Address address) {
        return addressRepository.update(address);
    }
}
```

-

```
public interface AddressRepository extends JpaRepository<Address, Long>, AddressRepositoryCustom  {

}
```

-

```
public interface AddressRepositoryCustom {

    void update(Address address);

}
```

-

```
@Repository
public class AddressRepositoryImpl implements AddressRepositoryCustom {

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

private JPAQueryFactory query;

@PostConstruct
public void setUp(){
    query = new JPAQueryFactory(entityManager);
}

@Override
public void update(Address entity) {
    QAddress qAddress = QAddress.address;
    JPAUpdateClause update = new JPAUpdateClause(entityManager, qAddress);
    update.where(qAddress.id.eq(entity.getId())).set(qAddress.number,entity.getNumber()).execute();
}
```

}

Based on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6222600/transactional-method-calling-another-method-without-transactional-anotation?answertab=votes#tab-top), "When you call a method without @Transactional within a transaction block, the parent transaction will continue to the new method". This actually works with the save method. However, on the update method, the following exception is thrown:

**javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query**

I want to know why this happens, what is the explanation?

Comment: Do you have a UserRepositoryImpl as well - so we can compare the classes?

Comment: Also add your spring config

Comment: @qtips The UserRepositoryImpl implements UserRepository. Since there is no custom method on the interface, UserRepositoryImpl is an empty class

Comment: @qtips what configuration do you want to know? I'm using spring boot

Comment: Ah I see. Not an expert, but shouldn't AdressRepositoryImpl be implemententing AddressRepository and not AddressRepositoryCustom?

Comment: @qtips No... Take a look at the documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html