# How to use FetchType.LAZY with ManyToMany?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I have two entities with many-to-many relationship.

in class Role:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();
```

and in class User:

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "role_user", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
```

And I get the exception:

> org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize
>   a collection of role: User.roles, could not initialize proxy - no Session

When I add `fetch = FetchType.EAGER`, I get another exception:

> java.lang.StackOverflowError: null

and cycle between Role and User.

How can I resolve this problem? I saw similar questions on Stackoverflow, but I didn't find real worked solution for me.

UPD:
Where the exception gets thrown:

```
@Service
public class UserAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {
    ...

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Authentication authenticate(final Authentication authentication) {
        final String login = authentication.getName();
        final String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        final User user = userRepository.findByLogin(login);
        if (user != null && passwordEncoder.matches(password, user.getPassword())) {
            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(login, password,
                    user.getRoles()); // problem here
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    ...
```

Comment: I am not convinced that the problem is in the declarations you have presented.  Please present a [mcve] with which one or both of the exceptions you report can be reproduced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `@Transactional` doesn't work for an overridden method of `AuthenticationProvider`. I should have created a separate service to handle this issue.

A similar answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23652569/8253837

Answer (score 3):

Hibernate already tells you why:

> org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize
>   a collection of role: User.roles, could not initialize proxy - no
>   Session

```
public List<Role> getRolesForUserId(int id){
    UserEntity user = userRepository.findUserById(1)
    user.getRoles()
}
```

This will cause an exception, because you trying to get the lazy fetched user roles without an active hibernate session.

`@Transactional` is your friend. The `@Transactional` annotation will create a hibernate session with a certain scope (e.g. Method)

```
@Transactional 
public List<Role> getRolesForUserId(int id){
    UserEntity user = userRepository.findUserById(1)
    user.getRoles()
}
```

This will work, because hibernate keeps the same session open for the scope of this method.

Comment: It didn't help me. I added `@Transactional` annotation and `@EnableTransactionManagement`, but nothing changed. If I configure `HibernateTransactionManager` and `SessionFactory` with beans, I have an exception about `bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.`
What else can I try?

Comment: I'm agree with the @Herr's solution. seems like your collection is detached from the session. also in model classes you can update the annotations. In class Role update the annotation `@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "roles")` and in the class User update it to @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL).

Comment: I updated annotations, but it didn't help. I tried to use this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30884155/8253837 and added `@PersistenceContext private EntityManager em;` in the class with     `@Transactional` method and now I have `java.lang.StackOverflowError`exception. 
Also my UserRepository extends CrudRepository, if it matters; but I created separeted class for  `@Transactional` method that uses UserRepository.

Comment: You should not need any extra configuration for this. Can you add the code where the actual exception gets thrown?

Comment: Do you use the annotation `@SpringBootApplication`?

Comment: So do you know what else can I try?

Answer (score 2):

Using Spring JPA try the keyword "JOIN FETCH" on your JPQL you can handle lazy initialization exception.
Example

```
@Query("SELECT u FROM User u JOIN FETCH u.roles r WHERE r.roleId = :roleId AND u.userId=:userId")
User findUserById(@Param("roleId") String roleId, @Param("userId") String userId);
```

Comment: It's not using Lazy loading in this case.