# how to avoid n+1 problem in many to many relationshipp

Tags: sql, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have `many-to-many` relationship in spring data jpa. The group Entity has many clients. And, the client belongs to many groups. In the `group` entity. I have this code.

```java
GroupEntity {
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "rel_group_client",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "group_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "client_id")
    )
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<ClientEntity> clients = new HashSet<>();
}
```

The `ClientEntity` does not have any field related to `GroupEntity`.
I use `findAll()` to get all groups. But at the same time I do a lot of queries for `clientEntity`. I don't want to query the clients. How can I do this?
This is where I call `findAll()` method.

```java
    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Page<GroupDTO> findAll(Pageable pageable) {
        return groupRepository.findAll(pageable).map(groupMapper::toDto);
    }
```

I have set `fetch = FetchType.LAZY` and add `@JsonIgnore`.They all do not work. I use `show-sql:true` to see the SQL. I can get a lot of SQL like this. I want to avoid them.
[image]

Comment: not an expert on jpa, but found this topic : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46810929/how-to-use-fetchtype-lazy-with-manytomany
don't you need a method with @Transactional for this ?
EDIT: fetchtype LAZY should work, please provide your code using it by editing your post

Comment: I have changed my question.Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Could you please provide the implementation of your `groupMapper`. Does your `groupMapper` access the `clients`getter and therefore invokes a call to the db to fetch the clients?

Comment: Fetchtype LAZY is the default type for ManyToMany and it works. No doubts. The question is what are you doing with the result of findAll? If the mapper access the field `clients` or any of its fields then it will cause Hibernate to additionally fire the select with join.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I generate other sql because I add `map(groupMapper::toDto)`.When I remove this.I achieve my goal.Thanks a lot.`fetchtype LAZY` works for me now!

Comment: This fixes the symptom but not your problem. You should check the mapper implementation and remove the access to the lazy fetched properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are accessing `GroupEntity.clients()` in your `GroupMapper::toDto`.